# how to use different package for different device in android?

Tags: android

Hi i have develop a application in android which run in every device, i use different layout for different size device's but i have use some code programmatically without xml  so, it create a problem in different size device.

so i require to change the package acording to the device resolution so, it can posible in android to programmatically detect and change the package class

plz, give some suggestion.

Thanking you.

i have use android2.2 for my application

Comment: Good question... but what you want is impossible. You can't change package runtime

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to programmatically change the application package. For device-specific display sizes you can create size-specific layouts as described in the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and use [`getResources().getConfiguration()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) to programmatically choose specific code paths to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Create an installer app which checks the device configuration and downloads the device-specific package afterwards from a ftp/network resource.

After installation, delete the installer and the .apk file.

Answer (score 0):

"i use different layout for different size device's " means you just use dp/dip sizes or that you have completely different layouts for each screen size?

If you only used dp/dip units, then you can add a scalefactor to your code to get the matching coordinates. If you are using different layouts, it's much more difficult. Depending on how many different layout configurations you have, you could build seperate apk files and upload them parallel. The Market will handle the distribution of the matching files then.